# Wireless problem when turned off on Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, windows

I'm having little problems with wireless connection on my Ubuntu 12.04. It works, but when booting on Windows 7, then turning the wireless off(`FN` + `F5`, in my case) then rebooting to Ubuntu, it just doesn't work, also when opening the network drop-down list, I can't check the "Enable wireless" option.

I also tried using `ifconfig` by issuing `ifconfig lo up` but still doesn't work, even though I'm sure that I only have `eth0` and `lo`. And I tried both of them with
 `ifconfig` non of them works(as far as I know, `eth0` is for wired connections, anyway).

More info:

-I'm running a Lenovo G470 Laptop.

-Output of `sudo rfkill list`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

If there's information's are not sufficient, then feel free to ask for more outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> phy0: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: yes

Reading the above, I would suspect that the shortcut you use in Windows shuts off the wireless at the hardware level (or in the BIOS) so that Ubuntu cannot control it.

The fact that you cannot click on the **"Enable wireless"** option tends to confirm this. The fact that you can use it if you don't shut it off in Windows also tend to confirm that this is the case.

Is there a reason that you need to shut is down?  If it's just to disconnect it, can you just disconnect the wireless inside of Windows instead of shutting it off?  If so can Ubuntu use it then?
I would suspect that if the first answer is yes the second one will be as well.